# GTMetrix: “Serve resources from a consistent URL”

Tags: wordpress, gtmetrix

We're getting poor performance scores on GTMetrix. It states that our images need to **Serve resources from a consistent URL**.

On the test results, it spits out what looks like the direct URL to an image used on the page and the same image with a ?____ query string at the end.

When I view the page source, I do not see this duplicate that GTMetrix says is being called -- thus the low-performance scores.

Some plugins we're using for reference:

- Custom built underscores.me WP theme
- Jetpack (not using CDN)
- WP Super Cache
- Autoptimize
- Smush (image optimization)

URL: [edited]

Report URL: [edited]

I've tried disabling plugins one at a time and could not find the culprit, I've also built many other sites using the same methods and have not ran into this error before.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the plugin you are using for your slideshow is adding a query string to the images when it initialises, then your browser is treating those as different images and re-downloading them.

I have attached a waterfall view of your image request, and you can clearly see the initial images downloaded then, re-downloaded with a query string. And the initiator combo-js.

[image: waterfall view]

Comment: Hmm well in the report it shows images outside the slider (logos in the footer) are also being duplicated making me think it's not the slider. For reference, I'm using Ken wheeler's slick slider jquery library http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ for the carousel -- which I've used on many sites without this problem.

Comment: oh right okay, well do you know what combo-js is? Because that is causing the issue.

Comment: Looks like you were right, it's that script (originating from an unrelated plugin we need -- dsIDXpress from diversesolutions.com) causing the issue -- it's just very strange that this shows up in the gtmetrix audit but not in the page source. Thank you.